# Has anyone got a working .Net Core SQL Server Client Implementation for Geospatial Types?

Tags: sql-server, nettopologysuite

I've tried and tried with this but support still seems laughably broken. The 2 options for a .NET Core supported implementation I can see are:

- NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes
- 3rd Party Microsoft.SqlServer.Types library

NetTopologySuite works for a narrow set of cases, you can read a Geometry from a DataReader, but DataReader.GetFieldType is broken, which in turn completely breaks DataAdapter.Fill.

The 3rd Party libraries seem to suffer from all kinds of loading issues and null references.

I understand that Microsoft seem to have abandoned getting this to work, but there must be some kind of solution out there?

Comment: Have you tried the [latest version of the package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/160.900.6-rc0)? This is marked "rc", so you'll need to enable prerelease and it's not technically final, but since the latest "final" version is from 2018 it's worth a shot.

Comment: My understanding is that this relies on the Windows binaries being installed or distributed and is therefore not a solution for .Net Core.